# SCP and SSH without using the Keys in unix

Tags: shell, unix

I am trying to do scp to copy a file and then ssh to execute a script on remote server.

My trouble is I don't have the SSH private/public keys generated and I don't have that option with me.

Is there any other way like to use the Authentication files manually for achieving this?

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Note: I can't find sshpass in my machine and also heard like its not that secured

Comment: Look up ssh agent.

Comment: ssh agent not installed..

Comment: So, no key, no agent, no sshpass.  You are SOL I think.  Something is weird, the agent and pass are included in the SSH package on most linux/unix i know.  You are making your life difficult for nothing IMHO.